# android - set starting point to top left on libgdx

Tags: android, camera, pivot, point, libgdx

i want to use libgdx as a solution to scaling of apps based on screens aspect ratio.
i've found this link , and i find it really useful:
http://blog.acamara.es/2012/02/05/keep-screen-aspect-ratio-with-different-resolutions-using-libgdx/

i'm quite rusty with opengl (haven't written for it in years) and i wish to use the example on this link so that it would be easy to put images and shapes .
sadly , the starting point is in the middle . i want to use it like on many other platforms - top left corner should be (0,0) , and bottom right corner should be (targetWidth-1,targetHeight-1) , 
from what i remember, i need to move(translate) and rotate the camera in order to achieve it , but i'm not sure .

here's my modified code of the link's example for the onCreate method:

```
    @Override
public void create()
  {
  camera=new OrthographicCamera(VIRTUAL_WIDTH,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
  // camera.translate(VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2,0);
  // camera.rotate(90,0,0,1);
  camera.update();
  //
  font=new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts.fnt"),false);
  font.setColor(Color.RED);
  //
  screenQuad=new Mesh(true,4,4,new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position,3,"attr_position"),new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked,4,"attr_color"));
  Point bottomLeft=new Point(0,0);
  Point topRight=new Point(VIRTUAL_WIDTH,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
  screenQuad.setVertices(new float[] {//
      bottomLeft.x,bottomLeft.y,0f,Color.toFloatBits(255,0,0,255),//
          topRight.x,bottomLeft.y,0f,Color.toFloatBits(255,255,0,255),//
          bottomLeft.x,topRight.y,0f,Color.toFloatBits(0,255,0,255),//
          topRight.x,topRight.y,0f,Color.toFloatBits(0,0,255,255)});
  screenQuad.setIndices(new short[] {0,1,2,3});
  //
  bottomLeft=new Point(VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2-50,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2-50);
  topRight=new Point(VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2+50,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2+50);
  quad=new Mesh(true,4,4,new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position,3,"attr_position"),new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked,4,"attr_color"));
  quad.setVertices(new float[] {//
  bottomLeft.x,bottomLeft.y,0f,Color.toFloatBits(255,0,0,255),//
      topRight.x,bottomLeft.y,0f,Color.toFloatBits(255,255,0,255),//
      bottomLeft.x,topRight.y,0f,Color.toFloatBits(0,255,0,255),//
      topRight.x,topRight.y,0f,Color.toFloatBits(0,0,255,255)});
  quad.setIndices(new short[] {0,1,2,3});
  //
  texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(IMAGE_FILE));
  spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
  spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0,0,VIRTUAL_WIDTH,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
  }
```

so far , i've succeeded to use this code in order to use scaled coordinates , and still keep aspect ratio (which is great) , but i didn't succeed in moving the starting point (0,0) to the top left corner .

please help me .

---

EDIT: ok , after some testing , i've found out that the reason for it not working is that i use the spriteBatch . i think it ignores the camera . this code occurs in the render part. no matter what i do to the camera , it will still show the same results.

```
@Override
public void render()
  {
  if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)||Gdx.input.justTouched())
    Gdx.app.exit();
  // update camera
  // camera.update();
  // camera.apply(Gdx.gl10);
  // set viewport
  Gdx.gl.glViewport((int)viewport.x,(int)viewport.y,(int)viewport.width,(int)viewport.height);
  // clear previous frame
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  //
  final String msg="test";
  final TextBounds textBounds=font.getBounds(msg);
  spriteBatch.begin();
  screenQuad.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
  quad.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
  Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  spriteBatch.draw(texture,0,0,texture.getWidth(),texture.getHeight(),0,0,texture.getWidth(),texture.getHeight(),false,false);
  spriteBatch.draw(texture,0,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT-texture.getHeight(),texture.getWidth(),texture.getHeight(),0,0,texture.getWidth(),texture.getHeight(),false,false);
  font.draw(spriteBatch,msg,VIRTUAL_WIDTH-textBounds.width,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
  spriteBatch.end();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
camera.translate(VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2,0);
camera.rotate(90,0,0,1);
```

should move the camera such that it does what you want.  However, my code has an additional:

```
camera.update()
```

call after it calls translate, and it looks like you're missing that.  The [doc for Camera.update](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#update%28%29) says:

```
update
public abstract void update()

Recalculates the projection and view matrix of this camera and the Frustum planes. Use this after you've manipulated any of the attributes of the camera.
```

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work - the green rectangle doesn't take full window space , and text and images don't show in the correct locations.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work well on android as well . i don't get what am i missing? i also wish to put the starting point to the top left corner , and not the current one (bottom left).

Comment: Your camera is rotated 90 degress ... is that messing up X and Y?  Try removing that line or changing it to 180?  Without pictures or some specifics its hard to know what "doesn't seem to work well" specifically means.  Might be time for a new question for that, though.

Comment: the camera is rotated because i've tried to set the starting point by myself . the original starting point is on the middle of the screen , so i first moved the camera to the  . i've rotated it because the axis values are not from top left - meaning that the more you move right and below , the more x & y increase . about "doesn't seem to work well" , i've given the example link ,which is identical to mine currently (since i didn't find a solution yet) . once i get to a working solution, i will publish it.